# Asp.net main website folder

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I got project that runs on main ftp directory copy all the files to new directory in the ftp with name "new"
And now i have a problem its no reconized the master page in all the aspx files because the path is 
~/templ.master
And if i change it to
~/new/templ.master

Its working good but i have a lot of files and codebehind (vb files) too that not reconized

So i ask for a way to change the main website directory on my project
That the project will take all the files from new dir...

How to do it?
Tnx a lot

edit:

again thats my files:

```
new/templ.Master
new/templ.Master.designer.vb
new/templ.Master.vb
new/default.aspx
```

in new/templ.Master there is a line like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="templ.master.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.templ" %>
```

in new/default.aspx there is a line like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/templ.Master" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
```

when i change in the default.aspx to line:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/new/templ.Master" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
```

its working but its not read the CodeBehind="templ.master.vb" its take the file templ.master.vb from the root not from the new directory...

and like i said i have a lot of aspx files so i cant change all MasterPageFile="~/templ.Master" to MasterPageFile="~/new/templ.Master" ...
i search a short way to do it...

Comment: Do you need /new in the url? If not, you can change web root in IIS to point new folder content. ...else you have to work on routing.

Comment: yes i do, and i working on ftp server not on iis...

Answer (score 0):

Set the website directory as main folder of the website and change the default mainpage in web.config as below:
**Web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
     <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />               
                <add value="~/templ.master"/>
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: like i said, its not only the master page its the codebehind to
its my header in my master page:
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="templ.master.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.TevaCastle" %>
its not reconized the CodeBehind file...

Comment: how can you say that codebehind is not inlcuded, have you included myHeader in trhe master page?

Comment: there might be some other error, check and verify all the current names of the files that are inluded in masterpage.

Comment: someone help ? @Abdus Samad

Comment: @user165210 I cant understand the post now..  can you explain the issue on an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^$" />
<action type="RedirectToSubdir" url="/new" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

If it doesn't work, do a manual process: Juts replace `"MasterPageFile="` with `MasterPageFile="~/new/` by hit CTRl+H in visual studio (select `Match case` and apply that for `current project`). Do a same thing for `CodeBehind="` etc.

Comment: never changed, its stil show me the codebehind and master page of the main directory and not in the "new" directory @Ronaldinho Learn Coding

Comment: if i cut off the codebehind its not effect on my page.. its still take from the default